# How to Serialize primitive types

Tags: java, serialization

So is there a way to achieve serializing the primitive data?

EDIT
Any Specific Example will be great.

Comment: Please, give us some code to work with. Do you serialize the object of your bean class which contains primitive fields? This should work. What does *is not happening* mean?

Comment: Define 'not happening'. What happens instead?

Comment: *"EDIT Any Specific Example will be great."*  As will any effort from the OP.  What have you got?  Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primitive types can be serialized using `DataOutputStream` class and deserialized using `DataInputStream` class

Comment: No they can't. They can be serialized with DataOutputStream (or ObjectOutputStream) and deserialized with DataInputStream (or ObjectInputStream). This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure they are neither `transient` nor `static`.

Answer (score 2):

All of the primitive types have write methods in the class `ObjectOutputStream`.  You can serialize any primitive via an `ObjectOutputStream` in this manner.  For details see the Java API page for `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: The previous answer applies too.